# Implement Android scale animation on one View/ImageView when get focus?

Tags: android, animation, view

I want to implement a scale animation to View (or ImageView) when it gets focus. Here is my current implementation:

```
public class ScaleFocusImageView extends ImageView {
    private Context mContext;

    public ScaleFocusImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged (boolean gainFocus, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if(gainFocus) {
            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.scale_up);
            this.startAnimation(a);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is my animation xml 'scale_up.xml':

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.5"
    android:pivotX="50%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:duration="175"/>
</set>
```

I can't get the scale effect when got focus in the end, I just see it scale quickly and shrink to original as normal. Why does this implementation not work how I expect, and how can I fix it?

Comment: the animation works so actually what you want ? want the animation should be stay till focus is on the imageview?

Comment: I want to the View scaled when focus, and become normal size when foucs disappear, thanks

Comment: ok let me check on my machine

Comment: hey i am able to do what you want on click of view but i onfocuschange not working . i will update you if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now try this updated code:--

this is the class for imageview:--

```
public class ScaleFocusImageView extends ImageView {
private Context mContext;
boolean flag;

public ScaleFocusImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context, attr);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (gainFocus) {
        zoom(1f, 1f, new PointF(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2));
    } else {
        zoom(2f, 2f, new PointF(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2));
    }

}

/** zooming is done from here */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void zoom(Float scaleX, Float scaleY, PointF pivot) {
    setPivotX(pivot.x);
    setPivotY(pivot.y);
    setScaleX(scaleX);
    setScaleY(scaleY);
}
 }
```

Comment: The animation works, but why the position is moved when the view get focus? I use LinearLayout in my demo.

Comment: not yet, when it get focus, the view scales and moves up to right,  afterr then, back to normal and move back orginal locus again.

Comment: im really confused what you really need to do?

Comment: just let the focused view become bigger, not move. But  this code will cause movement function, why's that? Do you get what I think?

Comment: means view's bound should be same just image should be bigger,right?

Comment: no, the view bounds should be enlarged around the focused view center point.

Comment: Pls check updated answer now you just have to use this imageview class no need for xml try and let me know if it works or not

Comment: Merry Christmas, at first! It works, and the specified xml scale config doesn't work. what's the matter?

Comment: merry christmas brother..!remove those xml , this code is only sufficient as i handled all things without xml in this code.pls try out..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43857/discussion-between-kailash-dabhi-and-gladman)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your XML animation:

```
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
```

By reversing the animation, the image won't be loaded shrinked but the animation will follow the reverse scale.

The xml animation file will be like this now:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.5"
    android:pivotX="50%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```